# send some paramters to detail from master in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

Im trying to create a masterpage detail in xamarin forms.Simple logic, user will click the button in navigation page and then it will sende some paramter to detail page and according to that params I will bind a listview from a rest service,but I cant send params to the detail page,I'm using this method but still got error

```
   private void Button_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var item = (Xamarin.Forms.Button)sender;
              Navigation.PushAsync(new PageDetay(item.CommandParameter.ToString()));
        }
```

My master page is like this

```
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="paux.Pages.PageMaster" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:paux;assembly=paux">
 <MasterDetailPage.Master>
   <ContentPage Title="My page">
     <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
        <ListView  x:Name="lstViewMaster" RowHeight="36" >
          <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <ViewCell>
                   <ViewCell.View>
                     <Button  Text = "{Binding ad}" CommandParameter="{Binding no}" Clicked="Button_OnClicked"/>
                 </ViewCell.View>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
          </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
     </StackLayout>
   </ContentPage>
 </MasterDetailPage.Master>
  <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
 <local:Pages.PageDetay/>
  </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

And my detail page is like this

```
  public PageDetay(string id)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

Any help is appreciated,thanks.
The error is exactly

```
namespace paux.Pages {
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;


public partial class PageMaster : global::Xamarin.Forms.MasterDetailPage {

    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlG", "0.0.0.0")]
    private global::Xamarin.Forms.ListView lstViewMaster;

    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlG", "0.0.0.0")]
    private void InitializeComponent() {
        this.LoadFromXaml(typeof(PageMaster)); // this is source of the error
        lstViewMaster = this.FindByName<global::Xamarin.Forms.ListView>("lstViewMaster");
    }

}
```

}
Some of xamarin users had complaint about this error and wrote this https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/25938/missingmethod-exception-default-constructor-not-found
I disable linker in ios but still same ,nothing changes.

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to write ,error is "System.MissingMethodException: Default constructor not found for type paux.Pages.PageDetay"

Comment: If you could please share the full code. I can't replicate that problem.

Comment: since you are specifying your Detail in XAML, it is trying to automatically create a copy using the default (paramaterless) constructor, which is missing.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was related to the title, I was missing the title in my Xaml MasterPage. In your lstViewMaster.xaml you have the title?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    ...
    Title="Your title">
```